# Excel Power query how to replace a cells value with another if it is null

Tags: microsoft-excel, power-query

I have a column that could be null, if it is null I want to replace it with the value in another column as below

**Prior to transform**

| Source Column | Replaceable Column |
| --- | --- |
| Source 1 | null |
| Source 2 | Rep 1 |
| Source 3 | null |

**Post Transform**

| Source Column | Replaceable Column |
| --- | --- |
| Source 1 | Source 1 |
| Source 2 | Rep 1 |
| Source 3 | Source 3 |

Answer (score 2):

- On the Power Query Editor, go to Transform -> Replace Values
- Values to Find: `null`
- Replace with: `7`. Press <kbd>OK</kbd>.

[image]

[image]

- Change the 7 in the function to `each [Source Column]`. This will be the function after the change:

```
= Table.ReplaceValue(#"Changed Type",null,each [Source Column],Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Replaceable Column"})
```

- Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. This will be your result.

[image]